# Performance impact of static constructor

Tags: c#, performance

**Update 2**
I finally found the reason and it was something completely different: The EnumExCore defined a static constructor like this:

```
public abstract class EnumExCore<T> where T : class
{
    // ...
    static EnumExCore()
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(Enum))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(T)} must be {typeof(Enum).FullName}.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

which I removed when posting the original question in an attempt to simplify the question...
Apparently static constructors have an impact on performance when calling static methods: http://www.codetails.com/2014/10/18/c-static-constructors-and-performance/

Im sorry for wasting your time..

**Update**
In reaction to usr's comments, I put together a compiling code snippet (Console App). In doing so I noticed, that the below mentioned effect cannot be observed in the console app snippet. In debug mode, the EnumEx is about 2x slower than the direct call to the delegate, in release mode they take about the same amount of time (I'd speculate on this being due to inlining here).

In my original test case, the helper classes (`Integer<T>`, `Integer`, `EnumEx`) were in a seperate (Portable class library) assembly and the test code in a Wpf app's `Loaded` event. When putting all the code into the wpf app, the results are the same as with the console app. So this seems to be an effect related to using classes from other assemblies. What could be the cause of this? Why is the EnumEx method so slow when defined in another assembly and the direct delegate call isn't? (Both the static field which holds the delegate and the method which is invoked are defined in the same assembly as EnumEx).

Console App Code Snippet:

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int Count = 10000000;
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            int val = 0;
            foreach (int loop in Enumerable.Range(0, 4))
            {
                val = 0;
                watch.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                {
                    val += Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleKey.A);
                }
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Convert.ToInt32: \t\t {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

                val = 0;
                watch.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                {
                    val += Integer<ConsoleKey>.ToInt32(ConsoleKey.A);
                }
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32: \t {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

                val = 0;
                watch.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                {
                    val += EnumEx.ToInt32(ConsoleKey.A);
                }
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"EnumEx.ToInt32: \t\t {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static class Integer
    {
        static int ToInt32(byte value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(sbyte value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(ushort value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(short value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(uint value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(int value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(ulong value) { return (int)value; }
        static int ToInt32(long value) { return (int)value; }

        static Type GetType<T>()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            TypeInfo info = type.GetTypeInfo();
            if (info.IsPrimitive)
                return type;
            if (info.IsEnum)
                return Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);
            throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(T)} is expected to be a primitive integer type or an enum.");
        }

        internal static Func<T, int> GetToInt32Method<T>()
        {
            Type type = GetType<T>();
            MethodInfo method;
            if (false)
            { }
            else if (type == typeof(byte))
                method = new Func<byte, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(sbyte))
                method = new Func<sbyte, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(ushort))
                method = new Func<ushort, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(short))
                method = new Func<short, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(uint))
                method = new Func<uint, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(int))
                method = new Func<int, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(ulong))
                method = new Func<ulong, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else if (type == typeof(long))
                method = new Func<long, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("T is not supported");
            return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, int>)) as Func<T, int>;
        }
    }

    static class Integer<T>
    {
        public static readonly Func<T, int> ToInt32 = Integer.GetToInt32Method<T>();
    }

    namespace Internal
    {
        public abstract class EnumExCore<T> where T : class
        {
            internal EnumExCore() { }

            public static int ToInt32<TEnum>(TEnum value)
                where TEnum : struct, T
            {
                return Integer<TEnum>.ToInt32(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class EnumEx : Internal.EnumExCore<Enum>
    {
        EnumEx() { }
    }
}
```

**Original Question**
I have static field on a helper class

```
public static class Integer<T>  
{  
    public static readonly Func<T, int> ToInt32 = Integer.GetToInt32Method<T>();  
}
```

where `ToInt32` points to a method similar to

```
static int ToInt32(uint value) { return (int)value; }
```

and another helper class like this

```
namespace Internal
{
    public abstract class EnumExCore<T> where T : class
    {
        internal EnumExCore() { }

        public static int ToInt32<TEnum>(TEnum value)
            where TEnum : struct, T
        {
            return Integer<TEnum>.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class EnumEx : Internal.EnumExCore<Enum>
{
    EnumEx() { }
}
```

Now tried to compare the performance with this quick test I put together:

```
const int Count = 10000000;
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
int val = 0;
foreach (int loop in Enumerable.Range(0, 4))
{
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        val += Convert.ToInt32(TestEnum.One);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    this.tbOutput.Text += $"Convert.ToInt32: \t\t\t {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms{System.Environment.NewLine}";

    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        val += Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32(TestEnum.One);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    this.tbOutput.Text += $"Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32: \t {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms{System.Environment.NewLine}";

    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        val += EnumEx.ToInt32(TestEnum.One);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    this.tbOutput.Text += $"EnumEx.ToInt32: \t\t\t {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms{System.Environment.NewLine}{System.Environment.NewLine}";
}
```

Which produces output similar to

```
Convert.ToInt32:             1041 ms
Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32:   42 ms
EnumEx.ToInt32:              1364 ms

Convert.ToInt32:             1010 ms
Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32:   39 ms
EnumEx.ToInt32:              1342 ms

Convert.ToInt32:             1010 ms
Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32:   41 ms
EnumEx.ToInt32:              1313 ms

Convert.ToInt32:             1020 ms
Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32:   40 ms
EnumEx.ToInt32:              1292 ms
```

Release or Debug build, with or without Debugger attached doesn't make much difference.

Can someone explain to me, why the `EnumEx.ToInt32` is so much slower than the direct call to the `Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32` delegate? Or is there something wrong with my test?

**Edit**
The `GetToInt32Method<T>` is just a helper method which returns a delegate:

```
internal static Func<T, int> GetToInt32Method<T>()
{
    Type type = GetType<T>();
    MethodInfo method;
    if (false)
        { }
    else if (type == typeof(byte))
        method = new Func<byte, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(sbyte))
        method = new Func<sbyte, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(ushort))
        method = new Func<ushort, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(short))
        method = new Func<short, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(uint))
        method = new Func<uint, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(int))
        method = new Func<int, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(ulong))
        method = new Func<ulong, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else if (type == typeof(long))
        method = new Func<long, int>(ToInt32).GetMethodInfo();
    else
        throw new GenericTypeParameterNotSupportetException<T>();
    return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, int>), target) as Func<T, int>;
}
```

Comment: Can you post executable code? What is `GetToInt32Method`?

Comment: Yes, see updated question

Comment: Still lot's of dependencies missing...

Comment: What is non-generic Integer? Why such simple thing is so hard to understand in code? I think you need a refactoring

Comment: Take a look at https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: My guess is that the two slow versions perform boxing (the first one does for sure). Without executable, or at least complete, code it's not possible to determine why you are seeing this performance profile. I have voted to close for now, reopen if the required information is added.

Comment: Something is wrong with your test. I've tried it in console app, release build, outside VS, and the difference between the last two methods is just 8ms (per 10M calls)

Comment: See the updated the question

Comment: Funny resolution :) You learned the value of an executable repro today. I suggest you delete the question since it serves nobody. That said I don't buy that the static ctor causes this kind of slowdown.

Comment: ok, I will delete it, thank you for your help.
I was surprised too, but I cant think of anything else, I can take the static constructor out and it's fast and put it back in and it's slow, without any other modifiaction. And the static constructor does nothing but the type check. In fact the constructor can do nothing and the same behaviour can be observed.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Convert.ToInt32` you are making in the first loop compiles to call to the override receiving `Int32`, because `enum`'s underlying type is `Int32'. This concrete implementation simply returns input argument to the output.

Other methods are not that straight-forward, as they first have to resolve a function, and then call it.

When it comes to compiling the solution, compiler can even short-circuit the call to `Convert.ToInt32` and remove it entirely. I'm not sure whether that has really happened, but having only 40 or so milliseconds for ten million iterations looks like the method was never really called.

The other two loops rely on heavy lifting in terms of deciding which function to call in the end, and then placing a dynamically dispatched call on the resolved function. Spending around a second for ten million calls looks like a pretty good performance for all that work.

However, that is still far far away from performance that can be achieved with static dispatching, especially in cases when code optimizer can inline the method and avoid entire call, which I believe has happened here.

Comment: Actually, `Convert.ToInt32(TestEnum.One)` uses the `object` overload and performance is bad.

Comment: Oh really, I read it the other way around. Now I don't see the point, because the compiler knows the destination address at compile time.

Comment: Yes, the JIT *could* convert that to a constant but it's not sophisticated enough to do that.

Comment: Source shows that `Convert.ToInt32(Int32) only returns its argument, and there is nothing dynamic there, including function address. That's why I'm puzzled that it takes long. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,ac1a3422e6436d68

Comment: It calls `ToInt32((object)1)`.

Comment: True. Today I've learned something. It would be interesting to know why is it like that, since Enum is an int in my test code and compiler doesn't use that knowledge. Now it has to box, then analyze type in a chain of if-then-elses and that takes forever.

Comment: If you take a look at my results again, you can see, that Convert.ToInt32 is indeed very slow compared to the direct delegate call (`Integer<TestEnum>.ToInt32(TestEnum.One)`)

Comment: C# is specified to not implicitly convert enums to ints which is a good safety behavior in general.